# Submitting a site to search engines when the root redirects to a sub-folder

Tags: 301-redirect, google-index

I have a site that has its content on a folder `/hertfordshire/`  with pages after this.  I have setup a 301 redirect from the root to the sub folder.

I have added the full URL to Google (still to be indexed) but Google has a record of the base URL.  Should I also add this to webmaster tools and get this indexed?  Google is going to end up indexing the same thing twice which i guess is not good.

Comment: Google doesn't index 301's, only the resulting URL.

Comment: the base index was done before I setup the redirect - not sure why it was indexed - guess google gets to see the new domain registrations.

Comment: Then Google will drop the root in this instance. As I said, Google only indexes the resulting URLS. It takes around 1-4 weeks until Google removes the original URL.

Answer (score 1):

URLs beginning with http://www.example.com/hertfordshire/ (replace www.example.com with your domain) will be indexed provided they point to actual data that adds value to the web.

As Simon states, URLs to redirect pages (with HTTP status code 301 or 302) won't get indexed as those pages by themselves don't add value. When browsers land on those pages and they are formatted correctly, they will follow the resulting URL and automatically try to access it.

Use webpagetest.org and attempt to access your domain (example: http://www.example.com/) and if everything is done correctly, then the first line should be highlighted in yellow indicating a redirect. then the next set of lines should represent URLs that belong to your site that users can directly access.